# ionic 3 with plugin woocommerce Authorization header malformed error

Tags: woocommerce, ionic3

Here is my code

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({
            url: "https://www.connectims.com/laundrylocker",
            consumerKey: "********************ec553",
            consumerSecret: "********************a2199",
            version: 'v3',
            wpAPI: true,
            wpAPIPrefix: 'wp-json'
        });
this.WooCommerce.getAsync('orders/').then((data) =>{
            console.log(data);
});
```

and it return this error

{"code":"jwt_auth_bad_auth_header","message":"Authorization header malformed.","data":{"status":403}}

Answer (score 0):

Although OAuth is a solution for using HTTPS not HTTP, the url described above is not HTTPS

Since the SSL/TLS is performed before you make the request, it will be encrypted over the network, where there is no encryption originally.

the above is usable if the server performs an SSL/TLS Handshake, also you don't need it as the server doesn't support ssl/tls in the first place.

A simple search would've answered your question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Link-only answers are discouraged because they become obsolete if the external resource gets unavailable. Please edit your answer and describe the solution you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ionic platform to programming. I guess you are connecting to woocommerce as backend of mobile app using rest api. Use and test this code to initiate woocommerce object:

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({
      url: "https://example.com",
      consumerKey: "ck_bd53........................afa",
      consumerSecret: "cs_..........................7",
      wpAPI: true,
      version: 'wc/v2', //or: version: 'wc/v3'
    });
```

version must be in this format: "version: 'wc/v2'". It worked for me.